# where is AndroidManifest in unity 5?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

Salaam
I want to build my scene for android in unity 5, but i get a huge error.\n
a part of this error:
    *CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
    .
    .
    .
    AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isGame' in package 'android'*

where is AndroidManifest to remove attribute 'isGame'?

Comment: Check the Temp/StagingArea folder for your Unity Project. The Temp folder is at the same level as your Assets Folder i.e. Path_To_Your_Project/Temp

Comment: I use unity 5, and dont see temp folder. My project only has a camera and a light (default unity objects when you create a new project). I try to build this simple scene for android but cannot, I get error that mentioned above

Comment: The temp folder isn't visible inside Unity. It's at the same level as the Assets folder. Ex. If your project path is C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/MyProject, then the Temp folder will be at C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/MyProject/Temp. Open the project in Unity, try building (let it fail), then look for the folder

Comment: I found that file but there isn't any attribute named 'isGame'

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem.
Just update android-sdk to version 23

Answer (score 1):

Go to Search and type AndroidManifest [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FL1n.png), open with Monodeveloper and edit `android:targetSdkVersion="type your version"`